# When Saturday is chosen in jQuery datepicker, hide specific options in a Select field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two form fields, a jQuery datepicker and a select field with 10 options. When Saturday is chosen in the datepicker, I want option 1 and 8 to hide from the select field.

This is what I have so far and it's not working.

```
$('.my-datepicker').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        var day = new Date(date).getDay();
         console.log("Selected weekday " + day);

        if (day == 6) {
                 $('#pickup_time > option[value="1"]').hide();
                 $('#pickup_time > option[value="8"]').hide();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code functioned ok for me.  I created a functional snippet.  I added a few lines.  One for removing the selected value (incase one hidden was previously selected) and an `else` to bring back all the options if a day other than Saturday was selected.

```js
$('.my-datepicker').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        var day = new Date(date).getDay();
         console.log("Selected weekday " + day);

        if (day == 6) {
                 $('#pickup_time > option[value="1"]').hide();
                 $('#pickup_time > option[value="8"]').hide();
                 $('#pickup_time').val(-1);
        }else{
          $('#pickup_time > option:not(:visible)').show();
        }

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type='text' class='my-datepicker' />
<select id='pickup_time'>
  <option value='1'>test 1</option>
  <option value='3'>test 3</option>
  <option value='8'>test 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Steve, may you please tweak your answer so that the original select children are first cached.  Then, instead of hiding them, mark them with a data attribute and append them to a hidden, dummy select field?  I always like to consider if the user can press the up and down arrow keys.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon I am not sure adding that functionality would help answer the original question and it would probably only muddy the water.  Also, the code as posted works just fine with the arrow keys for me.